# collapse dataframe by similar rows

Tags: r, bioinformatics, reshape

I would like to collapse the following dataframe

df

```
chr start    stop        gain loss pvalue_gain pvalue_loss
6 68838806   68857819    0    6    1.00000000  0.05105438
9 29779560   29788411    5    1    0.02320654  1.00000000
9 29788411   29809428    5    1    0.02320654  1.00000000
9 29809428   29831788    5    1    0.02320654  1.00000000
9 29831788   29899917    4    1    0.05145798  1.00000000
10   650294    727180    7    0    0.07759025  1.00000000
```

I want to collapse for each chr where there are the same numbers for gain, loss, pvalue_gain, and pvalue_loss numbers on consecutive rows. However, for these consecutive rows when the dataframe is collapsed I would like to use the start number from the first row of these consecutive rows and the last stop number from these consecutive rows.

for example-

```
chr start    stop        gain loss pvalue_gain pvalue_loss
9 29779560   29788411    5    1    0.02320654  1.00000000
9 29788411   29809428    5    1    0.02320654  1.00000000
9 29809428   29831788    5    1    0.02320654  1.00000000
```

would be collapsed to

```
chr start    stop        gain loss pvalue_gain pvalue_loss
9 29779560   29831788    5    1    0.02320654  1.00000000
```

Final output:

```
chr start    stop        gain loss pvalue_gain pvalue_loss
6 68838806   68857819    0    6    1.00000000  0.05105438
9 29779560   29831788    5    1    0.02320654  1.00000000
9 29831788   29899917    4    1    0.05145798  1.00000000
10   650294    727180    7    0    0.07759025  1.00000000
```

How do I do this using the aggregate function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,list(chr=chr[1], start=start[1], stop=stop[.N]) ,
                 by=list(gain, loss, pvalue_gain, pvalue_loss)]
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(gain, loss, pvalue_gain, pvalue_loss) %>% 
   summarise(chr=chr[1], start=start[1], stop=stop[n()])
```

#### Update

Based on @Michael Lawrence's comments about non-overlapping matches, one way to correct this would be:

```
setDT(df)[, .ind:= cumsum(c(TRUE,start[-1]!=stop[-.N])),
        list(gain, loss, pvalue_gain, pvalue_loss)][,
       list(chr=chr[1], start=start[1], stop=stop[.N]),
       list(gain, loss, pvalue_gain, pvalue_loss, .ind)][,.ind:=NULL][]
#    gain loss pvalue_gain pvalue_loss chr    start     stop
#1:    0    6       1.000       0.051   6 68838806 68857819
#2:    5    1       0.023       1.000   9 29779560 29831788
#3:    5    1       0.023       1.000   9 29831815 29831841
#4:    4    1       0.051       1.000   9 29831788 29899917
#5:    7    0       0.078       1.000  10   650294   727180
```

#### new data

```
df <- structure(list(chr = c(6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L), start = 
c(68838806L, 29779560L, 29788411L, 29809428L, 29831815L, 29831788L, 650294L
), stop = c(68857819L, 29788411L, 29809428L, 29831788L, 29831841L, 
29899917L, 727180L), gain = c(0L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 7L), loss = c(6L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), pvalue_gain = c(1, 0.02320654, 0.02320654, 
0.02320654, 0.02320654, 0.05145798, 0.07759025), pvalue_loss = c(0.05105438, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("chr", "start", "stop", "gain", 
"loss", "pvalue_gain", "pvalue_loss"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Really? It would seem to me that `setDT` might be a little bit slower because it has to first figure out what the input is before doing the "setting". `as.data.table` would simply call the relevant `method`  for the object being worked upon. I've never checked though.

Comment: @docendodiscimus, [just asked Arun](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20961354#20961354). That's pretty much it.

Comment: Are you sure this is collapsing consecutive values? It looks like it is collapsing by any unique combination of gain, loss and the p-values, which does not seem exactly the same.

Comment: @MichaelLawrence  Could you show an example where this wouldn't get the expected output? Thanks.  Here, I am grouping by those variables you mentioned and subsetting the dataset by taking the first element of (chr, start) and last element of stop.

Comment: What he wants is to reduce adjacent ranges. There may be non-adjacent ranges that have the same combination of gain, loss, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `unique` from `data.table` package with some modifications:

```
library(data.table)
unique(as.data.table(df)[, stop := stop[.N], 
                           key = .(gain, loss, pvalue_gain, pvalue_loss)])

#    chr    start     stop gain loss pvalue_gain pvalue_loss
# 1:   6 68838806 68857819    0    6  1.00000000  0.05105438
# 2:   9 29831788 29899917    4    1  0.05145798  1.00000000
# 3:   9 29779560 29831788    5    1  0.02320654  1.00000000
# 4:  10   650294   727180    7    0  0.07759025  1.00000000
```

Comment: this writting is very neat!

Comment: @DavidArenburg You may also need to correct for the nonadjacent ranges, perhaps with `foverlaps`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have genomic copy number data, you might look into using the `GenomicRanges` package from Bioconductor. You could define an object called a `GRanges` that formally represents the semantics of your data and thus is able to offer convenient and efficient functionality for typical use cases.

Here we construct the `GRanges` object:

```
gr <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df)
```

Now what I *think* you really want to do is reduce the adjacent ranges whenever the copy number value is the same. So we simply need to group the data by the copy number value:

```
grl <- split(gr, as.list(df[c("gain", "loss", "pvalue_gain", "pvalue_loss")]))
```

The `as.list` is necessary due to a bug in the methods package. Anyway, we then reduce the adjacent ranges and carry over the values:

```
reduced <- unlist(reduce(grl))
values(reduced) <- values(unlist(phead(grl, 1L)))
```

The last line is a bit complex. It would be better if the `GRangesList` remembered how it was split. Working on that now.

Comment: using this - df$seqnames <- rownames(df) before GRanges object construction